# If $3^{33}+3^{33}+3^{33}=3^{x}$. Solve for $x$.

Tags: exponentiation

If $3^{33}+3^{33}+3^{33}=3^{x}$. Solve for $x$.

So we have:

$$3^{33}+3^{33}+3^{33}=3^{x}$$

I added the left side and obtained:

$3(3^{33})=3^{x}$

The problem I have is that extra $3$. If not, I could have said $x=33$. Any hints in how to proceed with this problem?

Comment: You have almost finished proving that $x=34$.

Comment: Use the exponent rules maybe? What happens if you have $a(a^b)$?

Comment: OH YEAH. I got it. thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ 3(3^{33})=  3^{x} $, then $ x = 34 $ .

Answer (score 1):

For the last line of your answer:

3(3³³) = 3^x

Apply the exponent rules for multiplication and you get:

3¹.3³³ = 3^x

3^(1+33) = 3^x

Then we got

1+33 = x

x = 34

Answer (score 0):

$$a^b \times a^c = a^{(b+c)}. $$
I hope you got the answer as 34 now.

Answer (score -1):

$3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3=3^x$

Comment: Aha i like this answer

Comment: Thanks.  I've found that showing it this way a couple times sticks with students much better than just memorizing $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$